# Why is my Change event code not processing?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some Change Event code that I thought should work, but the change event process does not seem to be working. Can someone assist?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim wsInput As Worksheet
    Dim rngValues As Range
    Dim lRows As Long
    Dim dateStamp As Range

    Set wsInput = Worksheet("Input AX")

    With wsInput
        lRows = .Range("J26").End(xlDown).Row
        Set rngValues = .Range("J26:P" & lRows)
        Set dateStamp = .Range("J19")

        If Not Intersect(Target, rngValues) Is Nothing Then
            dateStamp.Value = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

I don't see any changes whatsoever to my file, so I am not even sure if the code is running. I am pasting values to the target range.

Comment: Just a note - you'll need to toggle events on and off with `Application.EnableEvents = False` and then `= True` at the end. This code is in the "Input AX" sheet code module, correct?

Comment: In a worksheet code module, `Me` refers to the worksheet, so you don't need to hard-code the worksheet name.

Comment: Press `Ctrl + G` while in the VBE. Type the following: `? Application.EnableEvents`. If it returns __False__ when you press enter, then type `Application.EnableEvents = True` in that same window. See if your problem is resolved. If this is not the issue, then you're probably in the wrong code module.

Comment: Since you aren't even sure whether the code is running or not, have you tried just to set a breakpoint at the beginning of your macro, pasting the cells and check if you hit the breakpoint? That wouldn't solve your issue but at least you know if the code is running and doing nothing or just not running.

Comment: I will try these options when I get to work in the morning. Yes, the code is in the Input AX module. Thanks for checking. I checked too. :) @Tim Williams, I am new to VBA and thought it was good practice to assign a variable to the ws names....

Comment: Can someone explain briefly why enableEvents is False at the beginning and True at the end instead of the other way around? I figured it would be the opposite of screen updating (because you're wanting it to execute and then stop.... I'm probably way off.

Comment: If you modify the sheet with `dateStamp.Value = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")`, then the change event will fire again because the worksheet has been changed, and then again and again and again. Turning `EnableEvents` off at the beginning prevents this.

Comment: @Bigben - in this case the updated cell is outside of `rngValues` so this would not result in an endless loop.

Comment: @Tim Williams Ah yeah missed that, good point. I'd still add it but that's personal choice.

Comment: I agree it's good practise to add the disable/reenable

Comment: I thought it wouldn't cause a problem for that reason, but I added it just in case. Also, I found the problem and feel a bit stupid. I opened a "module" and created the code in the module by mistake, instead of opening the "Input AX" code sheet. To correct, I moved the code to the "Input AX" code sheet and removed all references to the worksheet, and the code worked as intended. Thanks for the help!